# How to loop an array in array (dynamic navigation)

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array with some items. Each array could have (or not) an subarray, also with some items.

How can I call the subarray in a loop? It is difficult to describe, here is the code. I know the code/syntax is not correct, but the syntax should clarify my problem:

```
<?php
$subitemsA = array(
    'subA1' => array('num'=>65, 'text'=>'Labor', 'url'=>'#'),
    'subA2' => array('num'=>44, 'text'=>'Rare', 'url'=>'#'),
);

$subitemsB = array(
    'subB1'   => array('num'=>0, 'text'=>'subB1', 'url'=>'#'),
    'subB2'   => array('num'=>0, 'text'=>'subB2', 'url'=>'#'),
    'subB3'   => array('num'=>0, 'text'=>'subB3', 'url'=>'#')
);

$navArray = array(
    'Home'   => array('num'=>0, 'text'=>'Home',  'url'=>'#'),
    'Info'   => array('num'=>0, 'text'=>'Info',  'url'=>'#', 'subArray'=>$subitemsA),
    'Sport'  => array('num'=>0, 'text'=>'Sport', 'url'=>'#', 'subArray'=>$subitemsB),
);


$html = '';
foreach($navArray as $item) {
    $html .= "<li>";
    $html .= "<a href='{$item['url']}'><i class='abc'></i>{$item['text']}</a>\n";

    if (count($navArray) > 3) {

        foreach($navArray.subArray as $subitem) {
            $html .= "<li>";
            $html .= "<a href='{$subitem['url']}'>{$subitem['text']}</a>\n";
            $html .= "</li>";
        }

    }

    $html .= "</li>";
}
```

The first foreach loop works. But how can I access the subArray of Info and Sport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a three level foreach for this to work -

```
foreach($navArray as $key => $item) {
  $html .= "<li>";
  $html .= "<a href='{$item['url']}'><i class='abc'></i>{$item['text']}</a>\n";
  foreach ($item as $itemkey => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) { //Now Check if $value is an array
      foreach($value as $valuekey => $subitem) { //Loop through $value
        $html .= "<li>";
        $html .= "<a href='{$subitem['url']}'>{$subitem['text']}</a>\n";
        $html .= "</li>";
      }
    }
  }
  $html .= "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your question in more general way: **How to deal with multi-level nested array using recursion and template**.

```
function parseArray(array $navArray, &$html, $depth = 0) {
  foreach ($navArray as $item) {
    $html .= "<li>";

    // this function use template to create html
    $html .= toHtml($item['url'], $item['text'], $depth);

    foreach ($item as $subItem) {
      if (is_array($subItem)) {
        // use recursion to parse deeper level of subarray
        parseArray($item, $html, $depth + 1);
      }
    }

    $html .= "</li>";

  }
}

function toHtml($url, $text, $depth)
{
  $template = '';
  if ($depth == 0) {
    $template = '<a href=\'{{url}}\'><i class=\'abc\'></i>{{text}}</a>\n';
  } elseif ($depth >= 1) {
    $template = '<a href=\'{{url}}\'>{{text}}</a>\n';
  }
  // define more template for deeper level here if you want

  $template = str_replace('{{url}}', $url, $template);
  $template = str_replace('{{text}}', $text, $template);
  return $template;
}

$html = '';
parseArray($navArray, $html);
```

Just hurrily forge this code out of mind, haven't test it yet. Hope it help.

Regards,